# Does a Daily gained from a feat count against my current 3/day limit?

Tags: dnd-4e, feats, powers

I am playing a tiefling level 9 Rogue and I learned the Diabolic Soul feat that gives me the Diabolic Transformation daily feat power. Right now I can use only 3 daily powers in one day. Will Diabolic Transformation take away one of my three per day, or is it separate like daily item powers?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**TL;DR**: It does not limit your daily power usage, because there is not a limit on the number of daily powers you can use. Daily powers are granted and used independently of each other.

---

You have two things going on simultaneously here. I'm going to try to attack this from two angles. First let's talk about daily power limits, then we'll get to how this particular power behaves.

First and foremost, daily powers do *not* provide an arbitrary pool of "daily power uses" that you can expend on whatever powers you see fit. Your class, race, items etc grant you daily powers (the class powers we are referencing here as the "limit" are typically called "daily attack powers"). You can then use *each* of those powers one time per day (some exceptions apply, see Wizard). Based on your current level, feats, class, and many other factors, you may have one daily power or a dozen. After you reach paragon tier your number of daily powers from your *class* levels out and you don't earn anymore (you do still earn them from your paragon path, epic destiny, new items, etc).

Now that we have that settled, we can tackle the question at hand. There are two questions we have to ask: 1. does this power replace an existing one, and 2. does this power's text cause us to expend an additional power somehow. These are the basic interactions that a power *may* have that might cause the kinds of conflicts you are concerned about. Since we covered that there is not a pool of "daily power uses" the main concern of this question is moot, there is no real worry about expending those. However, we should tackle the other two concerns as well

1. Does this power replace an existing power. Yes! however, it does not replace a daily power, it replaces an encounter power (Infernal Wrath). This is not a class power, so it's not replaced by later level ups, but instead is a replacement for your racial power, so it behaves like a racial power.
2. Does the power expend another power. No! using the power does not expend any other powers, thus it does not cause another daily or encounter power to be expended via it's use. It does replace Infernal Wrath so that power is not available, but it's a complete replacement, not an expenditure.

So we can see that this power does not count against any kind of daily power use pool, as there is no such thing for normal characters (and even for characters like the wizard where there is something akin to this, this does not count as it's a separate type of power).

Aside: There is one particular type of daily power that *does* have a pool, this is the pre-errata daily item power rules. You got 1 use of a daily item power per milestone completed. This has been errata'd and is no longer a rule, though it may be enforced in some games.

Comment: More specifically, that limit is for daily *attack* powers. The power granted by Diabolic Soul is a racial power and not an attack power and therefore not subject to that restriction, the same way that daily utility powers are not subject to that restriction because they're utility powers rather than attack powers.

Comment: But it's not even that the limit is for daily attack powers, given that almost all Paragon Paths give a daily attack power at level 20.  The limit is for daily attack powers from your class, unless your class has a nonstandard mechanic (such as Essentials classes or Wizards).

Comment: @JLan yeah, it's complicated enough that I'm going to leave it as is. The limits are governed by classes and level, at the player's current level, that's the limit.

Comment: Do dailies give a shared pool, that can be used for any of them? I.e. if you have three dailies (from class), A, B, and C, can you choose to use C three times in one day (and the others not at all)? I was under the impression that you just got to use each daily once each day and that was that.

Comment: @KRyan Not in general. The wizard works like that...kind of (but not really). But no, usually it's just you use the powers in front of you.

Comment: I feel like this answer would be clearer if it said something like "The limits on daily powers is *only* related to how many your receive from your class; once you have a daily power, it can be used once per day regardless of what other powers you have or have not used." Or something like that. Emphasizing that the limit is really just the count of how many powers the class has given.

Comment: @KRyan yeah, I think I may need to rewrite this whole thing.

Comment: What about Black wrath of hell ?

Comment: @afagedon95 it's a power that's use is only permitted by the other power and can only be used once while it's active. It has no interaction with any other powers as far as expenditure goes (it gets a bit weird when you interplay recharging in, but usually a power needs a level to be recharged so...)

Comment: I used to play a wizard and i know there was a limited number of how many daily powers i can use, but now i was wondering if it was ok to just use them all in one day :D

Comment: @afagedon95 yeah, the only class that has restrictions on how many of it's given dailies it can use is the wizzy. (and that's because they get 2 at each level, total number of powers usable is the same, the wiz is just more flexible).

Comment: +1, This is correct and clear, but probably excessive. I'd add a summary (or TL;DR) to the top saying that "No, it doesn't count against a limit because you don't have a limit. You can use *each* daily power once a day, including this one."

Comment: The PHB _did_ set down limits on the number of daily item powers you could use, but it was in a little paragraph lots of people ignored and WOTC decided to totally overrule it out of existence in the rules compendium.